# Send an Email after several Tasks are done

Tags: sharepoint-designer, tasks

Like the title says: I'd like to send an email after three tasks are done.
All in Sharepoint Designer 2010. I can't figure it out myself and Google didn't really help.

EDIT:
Ehm maybe I wansn't clear enough on my problem...
I have a custom list workflow and inside this workflow I have several tasks.
After the three major tasks I want to send an email to a specific person.

Answer (score 2):

## Configure (or verify) outgoing e-mail in Central Administration

1. Navigate to *System Settings*
2. In the section *E-Mail and text messages (SMS)* follow the link to *Configure outgoing e-mail settings*
3. Configure the SMTP-server, from address and reply-to address

   - smtp.company.com
   - noreply@company.com
   - intranet@company.com

[image]

## Configure "Send Email" using Sharepoint Designer.

> If you use custom task process, you will have to manually include 'Send Email' action to send emails on different events.  If you want to send default task notification email, then change the 'SendDefaultTaskNotifications' property of your task process to 'Yes'. It is disabled by default.
>
> Mouse over on the task process and click on the small down arrow on the right to access the task process properties.

---

References:

- [How to configure Sharepoint 2010 Foundation to send email notifications when you use a hosted SMTP mail server that requires authentication.](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/2547-how-to-configure-sharepoint-2010-foundation-to-send-email-notifications-when-you-use-a-hosted-smtp-mail-server-that-requires-authentication)
- [Start Custom Task Process doesn't send task email notification](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f45f6ac9-ead2-4802-bad2-3dba732111a9/start-custom-task-process-doesnt-send-task-email-notification?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)